# Javascript add class and keep original

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using the following:

```
url=location.href
fname=url.match(/.*\/(.*)\./)[1]
document.body.className=fname
```

This takes part of the URL and adds a class to the `<body>` tag with the text extracted from the URL.

However the problem with this method is the class only gets applied providing  doesnt already have a class assigned.

Im really looking for something similar to the JQUERY `.addClass` function so body becomes:

```
<body class="originalClass filenameClass">

...

</body>
```

Comment: Just curious; why don't you use jQuery?

Comment: How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: @danit: `$('body').addClass(fname);`

Comment: @danit, why did you say similar to jquery .addClass() and then ask if jquery can do it???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With JQuery you can do `$("body.className").addClass(fname)` or similarly without JQuery you can do document.body.className += " " + fname

Answer (score 10):

You don't have to replace the class, just append to it like this:

```
document.body.className += " " + fname
```

You may want to run some validation though on everything that arrives via querystring...

Answer (score 6):

According to the [specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)

> classList returns a token list of the class attribute of the element.

So you can do:

```
document.body.classList.add(fname);
```

and it will work just like jQuery's addClass method. Only adding the class once and keeping existing classes.

You can also do:

```
document.body.classList.remove(fname);
```

if you'd like to remove the class later

toggle and contains methods are also available natively

Answer (score 3):

`document.body.className+=" "+fname`